# How to quickly find matching strings?

Tags: arrays, sorting, lua

I'm using Lua -- just an FYI, so after 10^10 digits, comparisons become invalid IIRC.

I have a list of 50,000 names -- that list may even increase into the hundreds of thousands. I'm trying to achieve displaying a list of potential matches for partial names typed in the search bar, so if I typed "And", these might pop up:

"Andy"
"Andrew"
"Andre"
etc up to 20 matches at a time.

Each name is unique -- there are no to that are exactly the same. Names can contain letters, digits, spaces, and periods. The table/array of these names is not sorted in any fashion when the code is run. In Lua, how can I, if it's even possible, display real-time potential matches when a user types a name into the search bar?

Comment: Preprocess your data and store it in a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  Yes, you can do it in pure Lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple program below works just fine for me. No fancy data structures, just plain brute-force search. Start a new query with `/`. End the program with `.`. Use `,` as backspace.

The list of words in `/usr/share/dict/web2a` has 76205 words. Its works fine too with `/usr/share/dict//words`, which has 235886 words.

```
local t={}
for w in io.lines"/usr/share/dict/web2a" do
    t[w]=true
end

os.execute("stty cbreak </dev/tty >/dev/tty 2>&1")
local s=""
while true do
    io.write("> ",s)
    local c=io.read(1)
    if c=="." then break end
    if c=="/" then s="" elseif c=="," then s=s:sub(1,-2) else s=s..c end
    local n=0
    print()
    for w in pairs(t) do
        if w:sub(1,#s)==s then
            n=n+1
            print(n,w)
            if n>=10 then break end
        end
    end
end
os.execute("stty -cbreak </dev/tty >/dev/tty 2>&1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every name is unique, create a db and store all the names in an indexed column and run a query with the LIKE keyword after every key stroke. The query will run quickly since LIKE is a string function and your index is string based as well. Depending on your technology stack, it would look something along the lines of this:

Lua is based off of ANSI-C and since ANSI-C doesn't provide key binding capabilities, niether does the default Lua library. However, I believe it is now possible to bind Lua functions to a keystroke, using the bind_key function found within the [Links-Lua](http://www.fifi.org/doc/links-ssl/links-lua/links-lua.html) library.